# HTML email templates - display different layout based on device

Tags: html, cross-browser, html-email

I have two templates for my HTML email: one for bigger screens, and one for smaller (e.g. BlackBerry or Android phone). How can I detect whether the HTML is being loaded on a bigger screen layout (for example, in Outlook or Gmail on a big screen) vs a small screen? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical way to do this.

Email is push based, so you can't detect the client in the request.

Client clients do not execute JavaScript, so you can't detect it with client side programming.

[Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) offer a slim bit of hope, but given the mangling CSS gets put thorough, I wouldn't expect many (if any) clients to support it.